# Looking to populate in an email a table with the headers in the left column and listing all the rows in the columns

Tags: vba, outlook

i have a function that runs a report from our tables and then returns it into an email and sends it to me.

the results can sometimes return more then one row. and my goal is to be able to list the headers in the first column and then the data should be on the right row per column, below is the code that I am using,

this works well for one record, as once it returns more then one record it will repeat the headers in the first column and list the second row of information in the same column, instead of adding a new column.

```
Public Function fHTMLBodyTablevertical(objRst As Object, Optional intBorder As Integer = 1) As String

    Dim strHTML As String
    Dim varFld

    strHTML = "<table id=""vertical -1"" border='" & intBorder & "'>" '<tr>

    Do Until objRst.EOF


        For Each varFld In objRst.Fields

            strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
            strHTML = strHTML & "<th>" & StrConv(Replace(varFld.Name, "_", " "), vbProperCase) & "</th>"
            strHTML = strHTML & "<td>" & varFld.Value & "</td>"
            strHTML = strHTML & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
         Debug.Print strHTML
        Next

        objRst.MoveNext
    Loop
    strHTML = strHTML & "</table>"

    fHTMLBodyTablevertical = strHTML

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out with using some arrays to help in the work of looping, instead of using the record set

```
Public Function fHTMLBodyTablevertical(objRst As Object, Optional intBorder As Integer = 1) As String

    Dim strHTML As String
    Dim varFld

    Dim vDat          As Variant
    objRst.MoveFirst
    vDat = objRst.GetRows

    Dim vhdr() As Variant
    ReDim vhdr(UBound(vDat, 1))

     i = 0
     For Each varFld In objRst.Fields

     vhdr(i) = StrConv(Replace(varFld.Name, "_", " "), vbProperCase)
         i = i + 1
     Next

    strHTML = "<table id=""vertical -1"" border='" & intBorder & "'>" '<tr>

    Dim d As Integer, u As Integer

    d = 0: u = 0

    For d = 0 To UBound(vDat, 1)
    strHTML = strHTML & "<tr>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<th>" & vhdr(d) & "</th>"
        For u = 0 To UBound(vDat, 2)
            strHTML = strHTML & "<td>" & vDat(d, u) & "</td>"
        Next u

    Next d

         'Debug.Print strHTML
    strHTML = strHTML & "</table>"

    fHTMLBodyTablevertical = strHTML
End Function
```